# What is the chemical composition of the human body?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elements

What is the average percent composition of each element in the average human body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- oxygen 61.3533
- carbon  22.8291
- hydrogen 9.9877
- nitrogen 2.5683
- calcium 1.4268
- phosphorus 1.1129
- potassium 0.20
- sulfur 0.20
- sodium 0.14
- chlorine 0.14
- magnesium 0.03
- iron 0.01
- fluorine 0.004
- zinc 0.003
- silicon 0.001
- rubidium 0.001
- strontium 0.0005
- bromine 0.0004
- lead 0.0002
- copper 0.0001
- aluminum 0.0001
- cadmium 0.0001
- cerium 0.0001
- barium 0.00003
- iodine 0.00003
- tin 0.00003
- titanium 0.00003
- boron 0.00003
- nickel 0.00002
- selenium 0.00002
- chromium 0.00002
- manganese 0.00002
- arsenic 0.000010
- lithium 0.000010
- cesium 0.000009
- mercury 0.000009
- germanium 0.000007
- molybdenum 0.000007
- cobalt 0.000004
- antimony 0.000003
- silver 0.000003
- niobium 0.000002
- zirconium 0.000001
- lanthanium 0.000001
- gallium 0.000001
- tellurium 0.000001
- yttrium 0.0000009
- bismuth 0.0000007
- thallium 0.0000007
- indium 0.0000006
- gold 0.0000003
- scandium 0.0000003
- tantalum 0.0000003
- vanadium 0.0000002
- thorium 0.0000001
- uranium 0.0000001
- samarium 0.00000007
- beryllium 0.00000005
- tungsten 0.00000003

Reference: Emsley, John, The Elements , 3rd ed., Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1998